# How to implement permanent splash screen and 1 time tutorial both in one app

Tags: android, android-manifest, splash-screen

I am newbie and I am making an app which contain a splash screen which is supposed to be permanent for every time app start and some tutorial slides which are suppose to work only on first start.. How do I implement it on manifest so that on first start first the splash shows and then the tutorial and then main activity and after first start on every start only the splash and then main activity, **so please can you explain in detail what i have to change with example in this particular case because em no good at coding**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hora.corp.srmtimetable" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/horalogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.hora.corp.srmtimetable.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.hora.corp.srmtimetable.WelcomeActivity"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.hora.corp.srmtimetable.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: can you please read it again an give me a answer to this rather than marking it as duplicate

Comment: You've declared both SplashScreen and WelcomeActivity as Launcher activities,  remove the intent filter for the WelcomeActivity, and when your splash screen is over after a few seconds launch WelcomeActivity, use SharedPreferences to check if it's the first launch of the app, if it is the first time, launch the WelcomeActivity or else launch MainActivity.
Checkout this thread on how to implement a simple SplashScreen : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172166/showing-logo-3-seconds-before-loading-mainactivity/39172351#39172351